# How to do transparent circle on SVG image?

Tags: css, svg, mask

I'm working on SVG game like Worms, but i don´t know how to do SVG terrain. I have created bitmap with logic ( when a bullet hits terrain, it makes crater). And now i got idea i give SVG terrain (img) on bitmap and everytime the bullet hits terrain, it draws svg circle. I know how to do svg circle, but i can´t see background, because the circle hides my background.
So my question is: How can i make transparent circle on SVG image ?

This is what i did https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo0iZ.jpg

This is what i want
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U2sP.jpg but SVG.

Thanks for help

Comment: Please provide a context to your question

Answer (score 2):

You can control the background of an svg circle with the `fill` property, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill). But I'm not sure setting `fill: none` or `fill: transparent` is going to achieve what you want, you would simply see the green background trough the circle. So to "cut" out a circle from the green part you would need to use a `clipPath`, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking);

Answer (score 1):

For this I would use clipPath.  In order to clip a circle out of the polygon you will need a path: a rectangle as big as the svg canvas with a circular hole in it:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="300">
<path d="M0,0h100v100h-100v-100M60,50a10,10 0 0 0 -20,0a10,10 0 0 0 20,0" />
</svg>
```

The path is builded out of a rect: `M0,0h100v100h-100v-100M60,50` drawn clockwise and a circle drawn counterclockwise. For a circle with a radius of 10 and the center in the {x:50,y:50} you would do something like this: `M60,50a10,10 0 0 0 -20,0a10,10 0 0 0 20,0`.

Next you use this path as a clipping path to perforate the polygon:

```css
svg{border:1px solid;background:gold}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="300">
<clipPath id="clip">
         <path d="M0,0h100v100h-100v-100
                  M60,50a10,10 0 0 0 -20,0a10,10 0 0 0 20,0" />
</clipPath>
   
  <polygon points="0,90 70,30 100,80 100,100 0,100" clip-path="url(#clip)" />
    
</svg>
```

If you need to cut several circles out of the polygon you need to change the `d` attribute for the clipping path by adding a new circle like so:

```
d="M0,0h100v100h-100v-100
   M60,50a10,10 0 0 0 -20,0a10,10 0 0 0 20,0
   M40,60a10,10 0 0 0 -20,0a10,10 0 0 0 20,0"
```

And this is a demo:

```css
svg{border:1px solid;background:gold}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="300">
<clipPath id="clip">
         <path d="M0,0h100v100h-100v-100
                  M60,50a10,10 0 0 0 -20,0a10,10 0 0 0 20,0
                  M40,60a10,10 0 0 0 -20,0a10,10 0 0 0 20,0" />
</clipPath>
   
  <polygon points="0,90 70,30 100,80 100,100 0,100" clip-path="url(#clip)" />    
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

To draw a transparent circle in svg you should use the command `circle` attribute `fill=none` like this:

```
<svg viewbox "0 0 200 200" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<view id="one" viewBox="0 0 200 200" />

<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="40" stroke="red"  stroke-width="5" fill=none />  
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="60" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" fill=none />  


</svg>
```